# How to update every 2 mins location to the server in android

Tags: android, service

I want to update the location for every 2 minutes to the server, I started the timer in onResume ,within the timer class I started the API Rest Calls but when the application is destroyed means I cant able to call the Rest Call.

I have a doubt whether I have to put timer in service class ,where to put the timer.

Mainactivity.java

```
public class UserHomePage extends AppCompatActivity i {
  SharedPreferences gs_sharepref_latlong;
      @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.access_token));
        setContentView(R.layout.user_activity_home);
        ctx=this;
        Intent intent = new Intent(ctx,
                MyLocationService.class);
          startService(intent);
 }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        }
 @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
          }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
       }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
      myTask = new MyTimerTask();
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(myTask, 0, 120000);

    }
   // timer task to sending lat and long for each 2 minutes
    class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
  ctx.startService(new Intent(ctx,MyLocationService.class));
 gs_sharepref_latlong = ctx.getSharedPreferences("myprefer", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 String gs_str_Latitude1 = gs_sharepref_latlong.getString("Lat", null);
                   String gs_str_Longitude1 = gs_sharepref_latlong.getString("Long", null);
           GS_UserUpdateLocation(ctx,gs_str_Latitude1,gs_str_Longitude1);
                 // Toast.makeText(ctx, "LATLONG-**-" + gs_str_Latitude1 + "***********" + gs_str_Longitude1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
            });
        }
    }
 public void GS_UserUpdateLocation(Context context, final String gs_var_latitude, final String gs_var_longitude) {
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, ServerUtils.GS_UserLocationupdate,
                new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                    }
                },
                new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
                params.put("gs_userId",  gs_var_userid);
                params.put("gs_lattitude",  gs_var_latitude);
                params.put("gs_longitude",  gs_var_longitude);
                return params;
            }

        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

        }
```

service class

```
public class MyLocationService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
 LocationManager locationManager ;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Timer timer;
    MyTimerTask myTask;
    String gs_var_userid,gs_var_roleid;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = null;
    private LatLng gs_var_mLatLng;

    private static final LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create()
            .setInterval(12000)
            .setFastestInterval(16)
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    public static boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    public static boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
  //to check gps is enabled or not
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        buildGoogleApiClient();

    }
  @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
     //   Log.i("RR","----destroy--");

        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }
    private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        try {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        try {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
             return;
            }
            if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient,
                    REQUEST,
                    this);  // LocationListener
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    // to get current latitude and longitude
    // storing the updated latitde and longitude when user moving and reach destination
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        try {
            gs_var_mLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            Log.i("WW","service class"+gs_var_mLatLng);

            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myprefer", MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            gs_var_userid=Prefs.getuserid(getApplicationContext());


            editor.putString("Lat", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
            editor.putString("Long", String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));

            editor.commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
  return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;


}
```

Note:If I put timer in start command its showing null object latitude and longitude before executing onLocationchanged ,onstartcommand is exicuted.Please kindly help me.I want to update the location even though application is  destroyed state

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
.setInterval(120000)
.setFastestInterval(120000)
```

to get location every 2 minutes.

Comment: So need to put timer in mainactivity also right.just we need to start the service thats enough right?

Comment: I have one doubt,service shouldn't be too long but intentservice is too long time it will be run,but location updates am using service only,it wont stop right?please reply me